# C# Simplest possible XAML window for .NET media player

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, media-player

I'm having a problem with  trying to play a simple mp4 video file with the `Windows.Media.Playback` functionality from a windows forms C# application. This should be really easy according to the example on the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer

I have simple windows forms app that starts the player and shows state of the player and possible errors on message boxes.

The message on the `MessageBox` shows status playing and nothing is being displayed but the sound of the video is heard. I assume this has to do with the ui component not being configured for the `MediaPlayer`. There is some `Use MediaPlayerElement to render video in XAML` xaml example on the page though that (as I understand it) should create a window for the media player, but I have no Idea how I would such xaml into this minimalistic C# Forms app. I would need to get the video image to also show on a simple window (launch a new window). I have 0 experience with anything else windows ui related stuff except for the Windows Forms stuff and I'm quite stuck with this as I could not find any simple examples on how to add a XAML window to this kind of C# Windows Forms application in Visual Studio.

```
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Media.Playback;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MediaPlayer p;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        p = new MediaPlayer();
        p.MediaFailed += failure;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void failure(MediaPlayer p, MediaPlayerFailedEventArgs a) {
        
        MessageBox.Show(a.ErrorMessage, "Error");
    
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        p.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("C:/sfc.mp4"));
        
        p.Play();//Start the media player

        MessageBox.Show(p.CurrentState.ToString(), "Player state");//Says "Opening"
        //Wait for few seconds
        MessageBox.Show(p.CurrentState.ToString(), "Player state");//Says "Playing" and we get sound output

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that player meant to display the video? You just created a Mediaplayer, it doesn't look like you have set a composition surface that can render the frames. There's a Control for WinForms in the [Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32) that implements an ICompositionSurface -- If you just need to reproduce a video file, you can also use a WebView2 Control, for example

Comment: @Jimi The video should be displayed in a new window with resolution equal to the video file

Comment: @Jimi Could you add an example of using that WebView2 for starting the video?

Answer (score 2):

If you opt for utilizing WebView as Media Player, add the [WebView2 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2).

After that, create a Form that's used to present the video files (here, named `VideoFilePlayer`) and drop a WebView2 Control (here, named `webView`) from the Toolbox.
Replace the default code in the Form with the code you find here.

Setup some properties of this Form:

```
AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
AutoSize = true; 
AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

Pass the Uri of the Video file in the Constructor of the Form:

```
var uri = new Uri("[Path to the video file]"));  
VideoFilePlayer videoPlayer = new(uri);
videoPlayer.Show();
```

If the WebView2 Control completes its initialization successfully, we subscribe to two events: [NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigationcompleted) and [ContainsFullScreenElementChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.containsfullscreenelementchanged).

- The former notifies when the WebView2 Control is done loading the content. It then executes a script that retrieves the computed size of the media and sizes the WebView2 Control accordingly. The Form is set to auto-size, so it also resizes itself.
- The latter is raised when you select the full-screen mode in the media player's UI.
  When full-screen is requested, the Form is maximized and the WebView2 Control is sized to the Form's `ClientSize`.
  The cached size of the current media is reset when leaving full-screen mode.

---

```
public partial class VideoFilePlayer : Form {
    Uri? mediaURI = null;
    Size mediaComputedSize = Size.Empty;

    public VideoFilePlayer() => InitializeComponent();
    public VideoFilePlayer(Uri mediaAddress) : this() => mediaURI = mediaAddress;

    protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        await InitializeWebView2();
    }

    private async Task InitializeWebView2() {
        webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        webView.Source = mediaURI;
    }

    private void CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.IsSuccess) {
            webView.NavigationCompleted += async (s, a) => {
                mediaComputedSize = await GetVideoFileSizeAsync();
                webView.Size = mediaComputedSize;
            };

            webView.CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElementChanged += (o, a) => {
                FullScreenToggle(webView.CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElement);
            };
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Core WebView component initialization failed");
        Close();
    }

    void FullScreenToggle(bool isFullScreen) {
        FormBorderStyle = isFullScreen ? FormBorderStyle.None : FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        WindowState = isFullScreen ? FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal;
        webView.Size = WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized ? ClientSize : mediaComputedSize;
    }

    async Task<Size> GetVideoFileSizeAsync() {
        const string script =
        "var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('video'), null); {style.width + style.height}";
        await Task.Delay(200);
        var javaScriptRsponse = await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        var parts = javaScriptRsponse.Split(new[] { "px", "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        return new Size(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually simplified alot in WPF

Firstly, simply use a MediaElement

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="topPanel">            
        <Button Name="browseMediaButton" Click="browseMediaButton_Click" Margin="5,0" Padding="3,1" MinWidth="50">Select Video File</Button>
        <Label Name="messageLabel" Foreground="Red" FontSize="16"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Name="videoGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaVideo" Source="" LoadedBehavior="Manual"  UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />
    </Grid>
```

Then in your code, after opening your file, play it

```
private void browseMediaButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.CheckPathExists = true;
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            bool? result = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                messageLabel.Content = "";
                mediaVideo.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
                mediaVideo.Play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would I add this WPF window into my WinForms app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218050/7676905